# TextInputType.datetime is not showing '/' & ':' symbols

Tags: flutter, datetime, textformfield

As in image symbol **/ & :** is not present.

[image]

While everything else and code is fine and is also working on my another device.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same keyboard on the other device (the one which is working)?
I can say based on my expirience that some keyboards do not responde to de input type and they just show a default or numeric keyboard.

For example on devices using SwiftKey, when keyboard is set to only numeric it doesn't change anything, just shows de default keyboard.

Comment: With same code the keyboard on another device is providing both symbols but not on this device

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems to be an open issue in [Flutter framework](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59685)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587